# Casting a sorted List back to IEnumerable is not returning any result

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting, ienumerable

This is the code I have that I need to sort it to ascending before binding. This is getting called from a different control that has the cars type defined and is attached to the Searcher property in this common control. So here I tried converting it to a list to sort it, the count goes to 0. So I am not sure how to sort it by a parameter of the cars type before binding to the grid.

```
IEnumerable cars = this.Searcher.Search(_enteredText);  //cars count 70

var carBL = Generics.CreateGeneric<IBindingList>(typeof(IMBindingList<>), 
     cars.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]);          

grdResults.DataSource = carBL ;
```

My code trying to sort the results thats not working. cars is returning a count of 70 after the search.

```
var orderedcars = cars.ToEnumerable().ToList().OrderBy(x = ?) ;
```

carBL count is coming as 0. I am not doing something right while sorting and the next line. I think I need to use ApplySort but not sure what the propertydescriptor should be.

Code for Search(text)

```
       public virtual IEnumerable<T> Search(string filter)
       {
            List<T> somelist = new List<T>(); ;
            if (lastsomelist  != null && this.Searchsomelist)
            {
                somelist = this.SearchtheList(lastsomelist  , filter);
            }
            else
            {
                somelist= this.SearchtheList(this.commoncontrol, filter);
                if ((somelist.Count == 0 )
                    somelist.AddRange(this.SearchtheList(this.multiSearchtheList, filter));
            }
            if (somelist!= null && somelist.Count > 0)
                lastsomelist  = somelist;
            else
                lastsomelist  = null;

            return somelist;

       }
```

Comment: You have a simple question and pasted a lump of code that is seemingly overly complicated, uses reflection and casting all over the place, what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I have a user control that has a datagrid and I need to send in the search text for it to match all the values in the returned result and bind to the grid. But its not as simple as it sounds. So I need to load those matches sorted (ascending). Line 1 and Line 3 was already there which I am changing to make it work that includes sorting

Comment: @Rianna - You can't just dump a lot of code with types that you haven't defined and ask us to guess what's going on. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: So, as I mentioned earlier. a) Change `IEnumerable cars` to `var cars`. b) At runtime, please type in `?cars.GetType()` into the `Immediate Window` after `cars` has been assigned. What is its type?

Comment: This is what I get at run time after I changed to var cars.I get the right type that was attached to the "searcher" from the Sedan form. 
{Name = "List`1" FullName = "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[XYZ.Core.SedanCode, XYZ.Core, Version=8.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"} System.Type {System.RuntimeType}

Comment: Is ` Generics.CreateGeneric` your code? What does it do?

Answer (score 1):

Would it work for you to instead do this?

```
IEnumerable cars = abc.Searcher.Search(_enteredText);
var orderedcars = cars.Cast<ModelClass>().ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Name);
abc.LoadallMacthingInventory(orderedcars.AsEnumerable());
```

Comment: I am trying it. Thank you

Comment: It did not sort ascending. I think may be I should not do var orderedcars. When debugged, the result shows up in a resultview

Comment: It does when I expand orderedcars, click on resultsview.

Comment: It seems that the original issue has been resolved. I think that it would be best to start a new question with the new issue you are seeing.

Comment: I still am getting carBL as 0

Comment: Apologies I thought you were saying you got them in order. What are you using to get the Count of 0. Debugger? Or are you calling and outputting Count?

Comment: Yes, the Debugger

Answer (score 1):

First of all `orderedcars.AsEnumerable();` is not needed here. `OrderBy(x => x.Name);` clause returns `IOrderedEnumerable<TElement>` which it turn derives from `IEnumerable<TElement>`, So you can directly pass `orderedcars` to `LoadallMacthingInventory` method like `abc.LoadallMacthingInventory(orderedcars);`. Hence the observation of `orderedcars.AsEnumerable()` yielding no result  is not due to `AsEnumerable()`. Instead you should look if `cars.Cast<ModelClass>().ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Name).Count();` comes more than zero. If it is coming zero my suspect is `abc.Searcher.Search(_enteredText);` is giving you an empty list back. you can confirm the same by inspecting `abc.Searcher.Search(_enteredText).Count();`.

Comment: I see the count as 70. I have edited the question also

Answer (score 0):

I got the list sorted using ApplySort before binding to the grid this way.Hope this helps someone.

```
 PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(carBL[0]);
 PropertyDescriptor myProperty = properties.Find("Name", false);
 carBL.ApplySort(myProperty, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
 grdResults.DataSource = carBl ;  //all sorted!!
```